# How to embed a jmeter jmx file in an executable file

Tags: build, jmeter, jmx, executable-jar, jmeter-plugins

I have created a test script jmx from Jmeter and I'm able to execute it in GUI mode and in non-GUI mode,
but it needs always jmeter application as prerequisite in order to invoke the jmx script as input to jmeter application.
Now I would build the jmx script in an executable file to launch it from cli and free from jmeter application.
Is there a way to build the jmx script (and eventually qith essential jmeter jars) in only one executable file ?

For example I have created the test.jmx.
It prerequisites jmeter and it can executed as /jmeter -n -t test.jmx

I would build it as or test.exe
and run it as  test.exe

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need an ".exe" take a look at [Launch4j project](https://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)

If you just want to have the way of running a .jmx script without having to install JMeter first you can consider the following alternative options:

1. [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin) (possibly connected with [Maven Wrapper](https://maven.apache.org/wrapper/) so you won't have to install Maven)
2. [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) tool which can [automatically download and install JMeter](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#JMeter-Location-Auto-Installation)

Answer (score 0):

thanks @Dmitri for you answers and links which has triggered the solution to the question
Other important links applied to build jmeter project with maven are been:

https://sarkershantonu.github.io/2020/09/04/maven-jmeter-reporting/

and

https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Adding-Excluding-libraries-to-from-the-classpath

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).